# assetsmanager-brunch is not working

Tags: angularjs, npm, brunch

i want to copy a file from app folder to public folder. PFB the coffee.script code snippet.

```
exports.config =
  # See docs at https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md.
  conventions:
    assets:  /^app(\/|\\)assets(\/|\\)/
    ignored: /^(bower_components\/bootstrap-less(-themes)?|app\/styles\/overrides|(.*?\/)?[_]\w*)/
  assetsmanager:
    copyTo:
      'myAssets': ['app/adminTool/assets/*']
  modules:
    definition: false
    wrapper: false
  paths:
    public: 'public'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a brunch plugin then I assume that it should be configured in the plugin section, like so:

```
exports.config = {
  conventions: {
    assets:  /^app(\/|\\)assets(\/|\\)/,
    ignored: /^(bower_components\/bootstrap-less(-themes)?|app\/styles\/overrides|(.*?\/)?[_]\w*)/
  },
  plugins: {
    assetsmanager: {
      copyTo: {
        myAssets: ["app/adminTool/assets/*"]
      }
    }
  },
  modules: {
    definition: false,
    wrapper: false
  }
}
```

Checkout: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md#plugins